# RSA Encrypt generates bad base64 string

Tags: c#, base64, rsa

I have simple `WinForms` with 2 `textboxes` and I'm encrypting the string like that

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] stringToEnc = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringTxtbox.Text);

        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
        {
            try
            {
                rsa.FromXmlString(pubKey.ToString());
                var encData = rsa.Encrypt(stringToEnc, true);
                encryptedStr.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encData);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

And my method to check if it's b64 string

```
private static bool TryGetFromBase64String(string input, out byte[] output)
    {
        output = null;
        try
        {
            output = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
            return true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In my **encrypt** method if I pass true whether to use `fOAEP` it **generates**
b64 string as supposed, but if I pass false the check fails, why?

If it matters, the encrypted base64 string is coming as `GET` parameter

Comment: The base64 conversion should work regardless of what kind of data you put in. Do you do anything else with those bytes? Working example without encryption: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Ej65j2 Your example is missing the most important step: The one between the two methods you showed.

Comment: Since you are saying string comes as GET parameter - sender either uses base64url encoding for it (which uses other characters instead of + and /, which should be escaped in url), or escapes unsafe characters (+,/,=) so ensure that you are unescaping them. If not sure - attach "input" string which fails base64 decoding to the question.

Comment: Fist, the RSA provider creates bytes, not strings. Second, the crypto providers are availabel for over a decade and work. Thousands of developers would have noticed a dozen years ago if they didn't. The same holds for `Convert.FromBase64String` and `Convert.ToBase64String`.

Comment: As for your problem, you are probably modifying the string in some way. Instead of using textboxes (why?) call `Convert.ToBase64String` and store the results in a *variable*. Then call `Convert.FromBase64String` with that variable. Do you get an error? If not, you'll know that the problem is in the UI code or in the way you copy/paste the text.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos O, really? Where did I said that the problem is with the built-in class or the textbox? Nevermind, @Evk helped enough. The problem was that the `+` character was getting replaced with empty space when I store it in variable.

Comment: The title. `RSA Encrypt generates bad base64 string`. It doesn't.

Comment: @Denisx so you *were* modifying the string. It's a good idea to create a *minimal* example in a new project when trying to debug something. A new console project or a few lines in LinqPad. Worst case, this helps isolate what *isn't* wrong. Best case, you'll find what's wrong immediatelly without wondering which call was actually the culprit